# Computer Heart Stopping Virus

Tags: virus, shutdown

If a virus causes my computer to automatically shut down when it is turned on and makes it unable to be turned back on, how does a person destroy the virus without destroying the infected computer's drive or files?

Comment: How are you sure this is a virus and not a hardware problem or severely broken Windows install?

Comment: That doesn't sound like a virus to me.

Comment: Are there any beeps just after powering on? Some machines with hardware errors will beep x number of times indicating the error. If so, let us know the model number and number of beeps.

Comment: is this hypothetical or is this a real problem?

Comment: no modern virus would do as you suggest. the computer has to be up for the virus to do its nasty work. that and there are very few viruses or worms in the wild these days. they've all be replaced by trojans. All that said, you don't want to continue to use a box that has a confirmed infection, because there is no way to ever tell that its clean. just back up your files as KoKo suggests, and rebuild.

Comment: Can you advise how far through the startup process its going.  Theoretically it might be possible for a virus to mess up the bios, in which case you might have to replace the motherboard (assuming you can't flash the bios).  This is a very unlikely, and possibly theoretical worst case scenario though.

Answer (score 2):

Burn/Obtain a linux live CD, and boot from your CD drive, and try to save your files by reading them in your linux environment.

Edit: I'm not sure if you have tried booting into windows safe mode, press F8 when you are booting.

Answer (score 2):

Among the other options of Linux boot, one could pull the drive and use a external enclosure, or hard drive to USB cable. 
[image: USB]

Or if you have an older drive (IDE):

[image: ide usb]

You can then hook it up to a different computer, scan for virus, check the SMART info, back up important files and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can boot from an anti-virus CD/DVD (something like Norton Antivirus, McAfee, etc). Just load the disc and hit F10 many times after pressing the power button. (It's possible your PC has another button to pick the boot drive). This will prompt you where to boot from (Hard drive, CD or USB). Then pick the CD/DVD. There should be an option on that antivirus disc to check your system for viruses and remove them. If it doesn't have this option, search for one that does (try google anti-virus boot disk/drive). You could also boot off a USB thumbdrive that was configured to boot and has antivirus software loaded on it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming here that you are using a Windows environment.
It is possible to use a live Rescue CD, it's a special bootable CD (or USB pendrive) loaded with an antivirus that can be run without the whole operating system. A couple of sample lists of those CD's can be found [here](http://www.raymond.cc/blog/13-antivirus-rescue-cds-software-compared-in-search-for-the-best-rescue-disk/) or [here](http://www.livecdlist.com/purpose/windows-antivirus).
To use one of them, you must download the image, burn it on an empty CD (or on a USB pendrive if your computer can boot from it), and boot it instead of the default hard disk.

It is also possible to use a Linux live distro (also bootable from a live CD/USB) to perform basic file backup/recovery, but if your system was infected, be sure to retrieve only the files that you are 100% sure to be clean, or you could find yourself with another troublesome situation when you will restore them. Basically any Linux distribution can be booted from a live medium, so the choice is yours, a light and easy to use one could be Lubuntu in example.

When you have performed all your cleaning and file saving, be sure to install and use an updated antivirus software on your system to prevent this kind of problems. Preventing is always better than curing.